# Can you compare propensity scores across models with the same data base?

Tags: machine-learning, data-modeling

For example, I have a customer base (a data set) and I am asked to recommend only 1 out of 3 different products to the customer at a single time.

The way I would have done it is that I will create 3 different models on the same customer base for each of the products, resulting in 3 different propensity to purchase scores. Assuming that the target for the 3 different models were balanced, can I really compare the propensity scores for the 3 different products in a literal manner and just take the highest score?

```
      Model1    Model2
     (prod 1)   (prod2)
cust1  0.1       0.6
cust2  0.2       0.5
cust3  0.3       0.4
```

Relatively speaking, customer 3's propensity to purchase product 1 should belongs to the highest decile, while his propensity to purchase product 2 is binned in the lowest decile. However, can you say that regardless of the model-specific scores, customer 3 is still more likely to buy product 2?

Comment: Why not? You compare the results of 3 models on the same test data and pick the one with the highest score?

Comment: My worry comes from 2 factors: firstly, the target is different so the propensity scores might be only relative to that target and might not be comparable across different targets. Secondly, even when the initial data prep uses the same dataset, final models might not necessarily use the same variables

Comment: what i truly meant was, can the propensity scores be compared on an interval/ratio level, or are the scores only relative (ordinal) to the model